# Error while running maven clean test command

Tags: allure

I am getting following error message while running TestNG test suite using maven clean test command:

---

**T E S T S**

---

Running TestSuite
Listener `ru.yandex.qatools.allure.junit.AllureRunListener@138450f0` must be one o
f `ITestListener`, `ISuiteListener`, `IReporter`,  `IAnnotationTransformer`, `IMethodInterceptor` or `IInvokedMethodListener`

Could any one of you help me resolve that.

Thanks,
Snehal

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a wrong import in ru.yandex.qatools.allure.junit.AllureRunListener

Check import is testng only.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on that? Do u mean I am using the wrong listener to execute test?

Comment: @SnehalWale yes, you are using wrong listener. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using Allure JUnit listener for your testNg tests. To fix the problem just remove listeners configuration from `surefire-maven-plugin`.

Check out the official testNg example https://github.com/allure-examples/allure-testng-example